# rolling window as a separate column

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I want to add new column which is only rolling window rather some operation or function applied on it. then I want to use that rolling window for other analysis.

For example:

```
df["rolling_20"] = df["Close"].rolling(20)
```

Please guide.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use some mathematical operation with the rolling window. For example:

`df["rolling_20"] = df["Close].rolling(20).mean()`

will give the mean value over the rolling window. `sum(), min(), max()` etc. can be used for your purpose. Please read the [documantation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html).

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Sir
I want a plain rolling window. I do not want any operation on it. Can I plot rolling date? if that is possible I will plot rolling Close with respect to date.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).